# SQL: Removing Columns With Null and Blank Values

Tags: sql-server

Below is the SQL query I am using to get our entity contact's name and address information from two different tables. Now I am trying to exclude entity contacts that have neither address or name info, which will come up as null or blank. In the end I want entity contacts that either have name, or address info or both.

```
SELECT
    [FirstName]
   ,[MiddleName]
   ,[LastName]
   ,[DateOfBirth]
   ,[EntityAddress].[StreetNumber]
   ,[EntityAddress].[fk_Direction]
   ,[EntityAddress].[StreetName]
   ,[EntityAddress].[fk_StreetType]
   ,[EntityAddress].[Apartment]
   ,[EntityAddress].[city]
   ,[EntityAddress].[state]
   ,[EntityAddress].[zip]
   ,[EntityAddress].[country]
   ,[pk_entity]
FROM [entity]
Full Join [entityaddress]
On [entity].pk_entity=[entityaddress].fk_entity
Order by pk_entity desc
```

Comment: Add a where clause and check for nulls & blanks for names AND addresses. Combine the checks with  OR condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    e.[FirstName]
   ,e.[MiddleName]
   ,e.[LastName]
   ,e.[DateOfBirth]
   ,[ea].[StreetNumber]
   ,[ea].[fk_Direction]
   ,[ea].[StreetName]
   ,[ea].[fk_StreetType]
   ,[ea].[Apartment]
   ,[ea].[city]
   ,[ea].[state]
   ,[ea].[zip]
   ,[ea].[country]
   ,e.[pk_entity]
FROM [entity] e
Full Join [entityaddress] ea
On [e].pk_entity=[ea].fk_entity
where (e.[LastName] is not null and [LastName]<>'') AND ([ea].[StreetName] is not null and [ea].[StreetName] <> '')
Order by pk_entity desc
```

Comment: Thanks irakiG. It narrowed it quite a bit, more then I was looking for but thank you none the less.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. as  **x <> ''** checks for blank string and if the value is NULL then UNKNOWN is returned instead of TRUE hence you'll be safe.

```
SELECT
    [FirstName]
   ,[MiddleName]
   ,[LastName]
   ,[DateOfBirth]
   ,[EntityAddress].[StreetNumber]
   ,[EntityAddress].[fk_Direction]
   ,[EntityAddress].[StreetName]
   ,[EntityAddress].[fk_StreetType]
   ,[EntityAddress].[Apartment]
   ,[EntityAddress].[city]
   ,[EntityAddress].[state]
   ,[EntityAddress].[zip]
   ,[EntityAddress].[country]
   ,[pk_entity]
FROM [entity]
Full Join [entityaddress]
On [entity].pk_entity=[entityaddress].fk_entity
where (FirstName <> '') or (MiddleName <> '') or (LastName <> '') or ([entityaddress].[StreetName] <> '') 
Order by pk_entity desc
```

Comment: Thank BoldCoder, that helped narrow it down better then my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
SELECT
    e.[FirstName]
   ,e.[MiddleName]
   ,e.[LastName]
   ,e.[DateOfBirth]
   ,[ea].[StreetNumber]
   ,[ea].[fk_Direction]
   ,[ea].[StreetName]
   ,[ea].[fk_StreetType]
   ,[ea].[Apartment]
   ,[ea].[city]
   ,[ea].[state]
   ,[ea].[zip]
   ,[ea].[country]
   ,e.[pk_entity]
FROM [entity] e
Full Join [entityaddress] ea
On [e].pk_entity=[ea].fk_entity
where LEN(ISNULL(e.[LastName], '')) > 0 or LEN(ISNULL([ea].[StreetName], '')) > 0
Order by pk_entity desc
```

What this does is, replace NULL by empty space, and does a LEN and sees if it is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you domenicr, that helped narrow it down and a bit closer what I was looking for.